# How to fill an oval Bezier curve

Tags: bezier-curves

I am experimenting with Bezier curves and I'd like to populate a bezier curve (oval). On circles it works fine, but when I curve the ends, the cubes no longer fit the curve. Attached is the blend file.
[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the scale of your oval curve, and once done, go in *Edit* mode, select all the vertices and right click > *Set Curve Radius > 1*.

Comment: Thanks for the straightforward answer!